# ¿Cómo coloco un string cada n veces entre los elementos de una lista en python?

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, while

En primer lugar, tendría esta lista:

```
Lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Querría colocar, cada 3 números, la palabra 'hola'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma relativamente sencilla sería crear una lista nueva, inicialmente vacía, a la que vas copiando los elementos  de `Lista`, y si el elemento copiado ocupa la posición `i`-ésima tal que (i-2) sea múltiplo de 3, entonces además copiar la palabra `"hola"`.

Así:

```
Lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
r = []
for i, v in enumerate(Lista):
  r.append(v)
  if (i-2)%3==0:
    r.append("hola")
```

El resultado en `r` será:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'hola', 4, 5, 6, 'hola', 7, 8, 9, 'hola', 10, 11, 12, 'hola']
```

Si quieres que el resultado esté en `Lista` puedes hacer al final `Lista=r`. Sin embargo eso no ha modificado realmente la lista original, simplemente se ha creado una lista nueva y la original se ha descartado (y el recolector de basura de python la eliminará).

### Modificar `Lista` "en el sitio"

Si verdaderamente necesitas modificar `Lista` en vez de crear una nueva, la cosa se vuelve un poco más complicada. Existe el operador `insert()` para listas, que permite insertar un nuevo elemento en cualquier posición que le pases como primer parámetro. Por ejemplo `Lista.insert(3, "hola")` insertaría esa palabra delante del índice 3, por tanto donde la quieres.

Pero eso ha cambiado la longitud de la lista, por lo que la siguiente inserción ya no la puedes hacer en el índice 6, sino que debería ir al 7, y el siguiente, en vez del 9, iría al 11...

Puedes llevar un contador para ir incrementando la posición en la que hay que insertar, pero la cosa se simplifica si los insertas por el final, pues de ese modo, aunque la longitud de la lista va variando, eso no afecta a los índices donde quieres insertar. Es decir, si primero insertas en el índice 9, luego en el 6 y luego en el 3, todo funcionará correctamente.

El enfoque genérico, para cualquier longitud de lista, sería por tanto:

```
Lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
for i in range(len(Lista)//3*3, 0, -3):
  Lista.insert(i, "hola")
```

La expresión `len(Lista)//3*3` es por si el número de elementos de la lista no fuese múltiplo de 3. Se empieza la inserción por el múltiplo de 3 más alto anterior a su longitud.

Answer (score 2):

Solo itera en un bucle con pasos de 3, y por cada elemento que agregues aumenta el acarreo(por que la lista se hace mas extensa y los índices cambian).

```
carry = 0
for i in range(3, len(lista),3):
    lista.insert(i+carry, 'hola')
    carry +=1
    
print(lista)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'hola', 4, 5, 6, 'hola', 7, 8, 9, 'hola', 10, 11, 12]
```